# How to start an Azure runbook/webhook using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation AutomationClient in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am using the .NET SDK to build an application which will trigger Azure automation runbooks. I've tried to start the runbook using a webhook but I am unable to find the method that will start the webhook and return a job ID.

I am using the **AutomationClient** from the namespace:

> **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation** Version: 3.8.0-preview.

Comment: I've not tried but seeing from the doc [`GetWithHttpMessagesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.automation.ijoboperations.getwithhttpmessagesasync) returns a task which has [`Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.automation.models.job) model there you can find the `Job ID` has one of the property

Comment: Thanks, @Jayendran but I think that `GetWithHttpMessagesAsync` is used to retrieve a Job that has already been initiated. I am looking for a method that will initiate a webhook or a runbook and then return it's Job ID.

Comment: The doc for this is lack, but you can try using other method to start the job and get job id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use AutomationManagementClient instead. Here is an example:

```
    AutomationManagementClient client =
        new AutomationManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert));

    // Create job create parameters
    JobCreateParameters jcParam = new JobCreateParameters
    {
        Properties = new JobCreateProperties
        {
            Runbook = new RunbookAssociationProperty
            {
                Name = runbookName
            },
            Parameters = null // optional parameters here
        }
    };

    // create runbook job. This gives back the Job
    Job job = automationManagementClient.Jobs.Create(automationAccountName, jcParam).Job;

   // then you can get the job id from the return Job object
```

For more details, you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/automation?view=azure-dotnet#overview).